# list-index hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am bit confusion of list index type,my mapping file has like below

`<list name="transactionItems" cascade="save-update,delete-orphan"
   lazy="false">
   <key column="TRANSACTION_ID" />
   <list-index column="IDX" />
   <one-to-many class="TransactionItem" />
  </list>`

whenever hibernate load a mapped object,its through exception **null index column for collection:transactionItems** please suggest me what can be the problem here. can you exaplain a bit about list-index?

Comment: What is IDX? how is it defined?

Comment: IDX is column where hibernate maintain index of collection;

Answer (score 1):

I am think it should be many-to-one , but that's probably not the reason you are getting an exception....

Comment: It should be an one-to-many relation only. what can be the problem there?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your code by referring this:

```
<list name="ListCollectionName" cascade="save-update,delete-orphan"
   lazy="false">
   <key column="FKCOLUMN" />
   <list-index column="IDX" />
<!-- column IDX should be created in your detail table you can also use any other column here and providing base if necessary. base 1 = the list will fill from index 1 byDefault it is 0 -->
   <one-to-many class="FullyQualifiedNameOFDetailTable" />
  </list>
```